# Return array object from a multi-dimensional array of objects that contains a specific Value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a function that acts like a search mechanism which goes through an array of objects and returns a particular array object which contains a particular value (search parameter) in this array

```
var jobs= [
  {
    "startDate": "5/2017",
    "endDate": null,
    "isCurrent": true,
    "seniority": "Senior",
  },
  {
    "startDate": "5/2013",
    "endDate": "5/2019",
    "isCurrent": false,
    "seniority": "Junior",
  },
]
```

I want to create a function where you provide an array, array key and an array value i.e

`nameOfFunction(jobs,"seniority","Senior")`

and it returns/logs

```
{"startDate": "5/2017","endDate": null,"isCurrent": true,"seniority": "Senior",},
```

Comment: `function(field, value) { return jobs.find(job => job[field] === value; }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: @str not really... READ FIRST BEFORE MARKING QUESTIONS AS DUPLICATE

Comment: @Dennis Compare the answer you accepted to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53737342/906113) in the duplicate question. Unlike you, I *did* read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array's [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method does this, but if you wanted to wrap it, you could do something like this...

```js
var jobs= [
  {
    "startDate": "5/2017",
    "endDate": null,
    "isCurrent": true,
    "seniority": "Senior",
  },
  {
    "startDate": "5/2013",
    "endDate": "5/2019",
    "isCurrent": false,
    "seniority": "Junior",
  },
]

const nameOfFunction = (ar, key, val) => ar.filter(obj=>obj[key]===val);

var results = nameOfFunction(jobs,"seniority","Senior") 
console.log(results);
```

Comment: How Can I alter this to return a particular value in the array e.g `"5/2017"` after passing `"startDate"` to the `findObject`

Comment: I don't follow, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter`:

```js
var jobs= [
  {
    "startDate": "5/2017",
    "endDate": null,
    "isCurrent": true,
    "seniority": "Senior",
  },
  {
    "startDate": "5/2013",
    "endDate": "5/2019",
    "isCurrent": false,
    "seniority": "Junior",
  },
]


const findObject = (obj, prop, value) => obj.filter(obj => obj[prop] === value)

console.log(findObject(jobs, 'seniority', 'Senior'))
```

EDIT:

```js
var jobs= [
  {
    "startDate": "5/2017",
    "endDate": null,
    "isCurrent": true,
    "seniority": "Senior",
  },
  {
    "startDate": "5/2013",
    "endDate": "5/2019",
    "isCurrent": false,
    "seniority": "Junior",
  },
]


const findObject = (obj, prop, value, key) => obj.filter(obj => obj[prop] === value).map(obj => obj[key])

console.log(findObject(jobs, 'seniority', 'Senior', 'startDate'))
```

Comment: How Can I alter this to return a particular value in the array e.g ``"5/2017"`` after passing  ``"startDate"`` to the `findObject`

Comment: I'have tried playing around the data and replaced the `startDate` values with `null` and I get `[null]` as a log... How do I perform a check to check if it's actually `null`

Comment: In short how do I get a string instead of an array as a log ??

Comment: The issue is that you are using filter, which will return an array of objects, and map will return an array of strings. If you only wanted to log each string, you could use the index, like `[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method on your passed in array. Here I have also used [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the value (`v`) of the current object from the passed in `key`. I then compare the value of the object (`v`) with the `val` passed into the function to see whether it should be kept in the new array.

See example below:

```js
const jobs= [
  {
    "startDate": "5/2017",
    "endDate": null,
    "isCurrent": true,
    "seniority": "Senior",
  },
  {
    "startDate": "5/2013",
    "endDate": "5/2019",
    "isCurrent": false,
    "seniority": "Junior",
  },
];

const filterArr = (arr, key, val) => 
  arr.filter(({[key]:v}) => v===val);
  
console.log(filterArr(jobs, "seniority", "Senior"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try out like,

```js
var jobs= [
  {
    "startDate": "5/2017",
    "endDate": null,
    "isCurrent": true,
    "seniority": "Senior",
  },
  {
    "startDate": "5/2013",
    "endDate": "5/2019",
    "isCurrent": false,
    "seniority": "Junior",
  },
];

// This function will return array of filtered elements
function searchArray(array,propertyKey,propertyValue){
  return array.filter(function(a){
      return a[propertyKey] === propertyValue;
  });
}

console.log(searchArray(jobs, 'seniority', 'Senior'));

// With new way

function searchArrayNewMethod(array,propertyKey,propertyValue){
  return array.filter( a => a[propertyKey] === propertyValue);
}


console.log(searchArrayNewMethod(jobs, 'seniority', 'Senior'));
```